# SQL Server XML schema: is there any way to add unique constraint on Xml?

Tags: sql-server, xml, xml-schema-collection

The following `create xml schema collection` code returns the error of

```
Msg 9336, Level 16, State 1, Line 34
The XML Schema syntax 'unique' is not supported.
```

```
create xml schema collection cs.T as N'  
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">  
  <xsd:element name="Column">
    <xsd:unique name="uniqueKey">
      <xsd:selector xpath="@ColumnKey"/>
      <xsd:field xpath="."/>
    </xsd:unique>
  </xsd:element>
</xsd:schema>';
```

Is there any way to set unique constraint by other ways?

Answer (score 1):

That is correct: `<xsd:unique>` is unsupported.  From [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/xml/requirements-and-limitations-for-xml-schema-collections-on-the-server):

> Currently, SQL Server does not support these XSD-based constraints for enforcing uniqueness or establishing keys and key references.  XML schemas that contain these elements cannot be registered.

As the documentation states, the same issue applies to `<xsd:key>` and `<xsd:keyref>` as well.

Comment: Is there any way to set unique constraint by other ways?